# Would love to learn quantum physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I would love to learn quantum physics and am extremely keen on it.
Lets get to points.

I was extremely weak at math and physics while I was in school, but I guess it's just the way things were taught. I have read some theoretical (the literal word) on quantum physics and am really keen to do the math involved. I love reading books and that's how I've spent most of my life. It would be the greatest thing ever if you geniuses could recommend a step by step guide (books only) to becoming a quantum physicist.

I intend to learn everything involved and/or required. It would really help me and many other physics enthusiasts who currently see no other option than the conventional university education route. I am fully and completely prepared for this journey.

Comment: I think the [theoretical minimum](http://theoreticalminimum.com/) by Leonard Susskind is ideal for you.

Comment: You had to know math at least on an entry level to take BSc course. Without this, you haven't chance.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1: Build your math fundamentals and physics understanding**

I recommend the book **"Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering"**. Focus on topics 1-12, 14 and 17. It is used widely as an undergraduate text for physics. Not a pure maths book, so it is perfect.

You should be able to do physics at A-level standard, and easily get an A. (Refer to British A-levels). If that's done, concurrently take physics modules from OCW as suggested. Focus on topics: Classical Mechanics and take some courses on Electromagnetism. Make sure your classical mechanics is solid.

**Step 2: Step-up to Quantum**

When you've got your math solid and classical physics good, I recommend the book **"Physics of Quantum Mechanics"** by James Binney. It doesn't delve too deep into the maths but rather focus on the physics and understanding behind it.

Lastly, I would say that the best option for you to learn physics is to do as many problems as you can. Also, if you don't have a good grasp of the math behind it, you probably won't understand it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I've always had good luck with MIT's [OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/): entire courses are uploaded to the website, allowing you to easily follow along without the need to pay for a conventional university route. Unfortunately not a book, but I've used it successfully and could likely provide some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend coursera.org.

There you can find free video lectures with best lecturers from decent universities. Moreover you cand find notes and programs that can help.

You can educate yourself there in almost every one area of knowledge.